# Generated ToList won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm very new to C# and I'm trying to make a basic little project. When I try to go to the generated index page (On the view -> Add -> View and then I just gave it the name Index and template List)

When I try to use this link to the index page;

```
<ul><li>@Html.ActionLink("Beheer", "Index", "Competenties")</li></ul>
```

I keep getting this error.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'DatabankCompetenties'
>   context has changed since the database was created. Consider using
>   Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

I tried resetting the Database, rerolling all the tables and using the command update-database, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: This error is actually occurring before your view is executed.  How did you create your database?  Is it a code first database?  If so, you need to run an update.  The root cause here is that your database schema is different than your models are expecting them to be.

Comment: It is a code first Database. I'll take a look! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are very new to C# I'll give you a very basic solution, which helped me out quite a few times.

1. Add-Migration (check which migration needs updating)
2. delete the recently added migration and the old one
3. Add-Migration  (Now you know which migration needs to be updated, so
   you can give it the proper name)
4. Delete all the tables in your DB (including _MigrationHistory)
5. Update-Database -verbose

Comment: That helped me! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You modify your Database schema, but you don't migrate the changes.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

1. Open the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio
2. Select the project where is the database classes
3. Enable-Migrations command
4. Add-Migration [Name] command
5. Update-Database command